# How to add data into grid in Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC without saving to database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik

Do you guys know how to insert data in telerik without the data being inserted to database ? Because I need to hold the data first and then create a button to submit all the data to database.

Here is my grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<COGS.Models.Invoice>()
        .Name("invoice-grid")
            .Events(e => {
                e.Edit("onEdit");
            }   
        )
        .DataSource(DataSource => DataSource
            .Ajax() 
            .Model(model => model.Id(data => data.InvoiceNumber))
            .Read(read => read
                    .Action("ReadInvoiceData", "Home"))
                    .Create(create => create.Action("CreateInvoiceData", "Home"))
                    .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateInvoiceData", "Home"))
                    .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("DeleteInvoiceData", "Home"))
        )
        .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(data => data.InvoiceNumber);
                    columns.Bound(data => data.Date).EditorTemplateName("Date").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
                    columns.Bound(data => data.RecievedDate).EditorTemplateName("Date").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
                    columns.Command(command =>
                    {
                        command.Edit();
                        command.Destroy();
                    }).Title("Command").Width("250px");
                }
        )
        .ToolBar(toolbar =>
        {
            toolbar.Create().Text("Add New Invoice");
        })
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
    )
```

and here is my controllers

```
public ActionResult ReadInvoiceData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        IQueryable<Invoice> data = connection.Invoices.Where(x => x.Status == 1 && x.WaybillNumber == null);
        DataSourceResult result = data.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

public ActionResult CreateInvoiceData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Invoice invoice)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var entity = new Invoice
            {
                InvoiceNumber = invoice.InvoiceNumber,
                Date = invoice.Date,
                RecievedDate = invoice.RecievedDate,
                WaybillNumber = invoice.WaybillNumber,
                Status = invoice.Status
            };

            connection.Invoices.Add(entity);
            connection.SaveChanges();
        }
        return Json(new[] { invoice }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }

public ActionResult UpdateInvoiceData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Invoice invoice)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var entity = new Invoice
            {
                InvoiceNumber = invoice.InvoiceNumber,
                Date = invoice.Date,
                RecievedDate = invoice.RecievedDate,
                WaybillNumber = invoice.WaybillNumber,
                Status = invoice.Status
            };

            connection.Invoices.Attach(entity);
            connection.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            connection.SaveChanges();
        }
        return Json(new[] { invoice }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }

public ActionResult DeletePOData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var entity = new PurchaseOrder
            {
                PONumber = purchaseOrder.PONumber,
                Date = purchaseOrder.Date,
                Origin = purchaseOrder.Origin,
                Vendor = purchaseOrder.Vendor,
                Status = purchaseOrder.Status
            };

            connection.PurchaseOrders.Attach(entity);
            connection.PurchaseOrders.Remove(entity);
            connection.SaveChanges();

        }
        return Json(new[] { purchaseOrder }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

EDIT : 
I have manage to add data without being inserted to database with remove this line

```
connection.SaveChanges();
```

from create function in controllers, but now how do i create a button to save all the data in grid to database ?, i assume it will use javascript to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is an example from KendoUI documentation website:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-sync

```
<script>
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  batch: true,
  transport: {
    read:  {
      url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products",
      dataType: "jsonp" //"jsonp" is required for cross-domain requests; use "json" for same-domain requests
    },
    update: {
      url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products/update",
      dataType: "jsonp" //"jsonp" is required for cross-domain requests; use "json" for same-domain requests
    },
    destroy: {
      url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products/destroy",
      dataType: "jsonp" //"jsonp" is required for cross-domain requests; use "json" for same-domain requests
    }
  },
  schema: {
    model: { id: "ProductID" }
  }
});
dataSource.fetch(function() {
  var product = dataSource.at(0);
  product.set("UnitPrice", 20);
  var anotherProduct = dataSource.at(1);
  anotherProduct.set("UnitPrice", 20);
  var yetAnotherProduct = dataSource.at(2);
  dataSource.remove(yetAnotherProduct);
  dataSource.sync(); // makes a request to http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products/update" and http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products/destroy
});
</script>
```

So in javascript, you have to find the grid widget, get its dataSource and invoke the sync method on it.

```
var grid = $("#mygrid.k-grid").data('kendoGrid');
var ds = grid.dataSource;
ds.sync();
```

Comment: it doesn't work, unless we create the datasource in javascript too, but i'm getting confused with the url thing for datascource

Comment: Razor code in question is translated to html and JavaScript to build the grid and datasource on the client. So can you explain exactly what you mean by 'it' in 'it doesnt work'.

Comment: "it" refer to sync function, when i run the code it return error like this "Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined"

Comment: Try grid.options.dataSource, using dev tool if your browser should make it easy to search for dataSource because it is there  somewhere I m sure